# Flutter how to display non filtered list on click on suffix icon in TextFormField search bar

Tags: flutter, list, dart, textfield, searchbar

I have a widget `FilterSearchBar` used in 2 others widgets. The first one `HomeScreen` contains a list of `Team`. In this one, I would like to display the full list of teams when the user clicks on the suffix icon in the searchbar. In the second one `PlayerScreen` I have a default `Text` widget and a list of `Player` appears when the user type something in the search bar and I would like to display the default Text widget when he clicks on the suffix icon. How can I do that ?

Here is the code.

**Team**

```
class Team {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Team({required this.id, required this.name});

  static List<Team> getNFCTeam() => [
    Team(id: 0, name: "Arizona Cardinals"),
    Team(id: 1, name: "Atlanta Falcons"),
    Team(id: 2, name: "Carolina Panthers"),
    Team(id: 3, name: "Chicago Bears"),
    Team(id: 4, name: "Dallas Cowboys"),
    Team(id: 5, name: "Detroit Lions"),
    Team(id: 6, name: "Green Bay Packers"),
    Team(id: 7, name: "Los Angeles Rams"),
    Team(id: 8, name: "Minnesota Vikings"),
    Team(id: 9, name: "New Orleans Saints"),
    Team(id: 10, name: "New York Giants"),
    Team(id: 11, name: "Philadelphia Eagles"),
    Team(id: 12, name: "San Francisco 49ers"),
    Team(id: 13, name: "Seattle Seahawks"),
    Team(id: 14, name: "Tampa Bay Buccaneers"),
    Team(id: 15, name: "Washington Commanders"),
  ];
}
```

**Player**

```
class Player {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final number;
  final position;

  Player({required this.id, required this.name, required this.number, required this.position});

  static List<Player> getPlayer() => [
    Player(id: 0, name: "Brock Purdy", number: "#13", position: "QB"),
    Player(id: 1, name: "Christian McCaffrey", number: "#23", position: "RB"),
    Player(id: 2, name: "George Kittle", number: "#85", position: "TE"),
    Player(id: 3, name: "Deebo Samuel", number: "#19", position: "WR"),
    Player(id: 4, name: "Nick Bosa", number: "#97", position: "DL"),
    Player(id: 5, name: "Fred Warner", number: "#54", position: "LB"),
  ];
}
```

**FilterSearchBar**

```
class FilterSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filterType;
  final TextEditingController searchController;
  final TextInputType keyboard;
  final ValueChanged<String>? onChanged;

  const FilterSearchBar({Key? key, required this.filterType, required this.searchController,
    required this.keyboard, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterSearchBar> createState() => _FilterSearchBarState();
}

class _FilterSearchBarState extends State<FilterSearchBar> {
  bool isClearClicked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.searchController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isClearClicked = widget.searchController.text.isNotEmpty;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: widget.keyboard,
        controller: widget.searchController,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(90),
            ),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          hintText: widget.filterType,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          suffixIcon: isClearClicked
              ? IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                clearSearchBar();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
          )
              : null,
            filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void clearSearchBar() {
    widget.searchController.clear();
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<Team> allTeams = Team.getNFCTeam();
  List<Team> suggestions = Team.getNFCTeam();
  List<Team> teams = Team.getNFCTeam();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("NFC"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FilterSearchBar(
            filterType: "Search team",
            searchController: searchController,
            keyboard: TextInputType.text,
            onChanged: searchTeam,
          ),
          showAllTeams(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showAllTeams() => Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: teams.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final team = teams[index];

            return Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          team.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PlayerScreen(team: team.name),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      );

  void searchTeam(String query) {
    suggestions = allTeams.where((team) {
      final teamName = team.name.startsWith(query.toLowerCase());

      return teamName;
    }).toList();
    setState(() => teams = suggestions.isEmpty ? allTeams : suggestions);
  }
}
```

**PlayerScreen**

```
class PlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String team;

  const PlayerScreen({Key? key, required this.team}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayerScreen> createState() => _PlayerScreenState();
}

class _PlayerScreenState extends State<PlayerScreen> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<Player> allPayers = Player.getPlayer();
  List<Player> suggestions = Player.getPlayer();
  List<Player> players = Player.getPlayer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.team),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FilterSearchBar(
              filterType: "Search player",
              searchController: searchController,
              keyboard: TextInputType.text,
              onChanged: searchPlayer,
            ),
            searchController.text.isNotEmpty ? showAllPlayers() : Center(
              child: Text(
                "No player found",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget showAllPlayers() => Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: players.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final player = players[index];

          return Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        player.number,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                      Text(
                        player.position,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                      Text(
                        player.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 1,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
    ),
  );

  void searchPlayer(String query) {
    suggestions = allPayers.where((player) {
      final playerName = player.name.startsWith(query.toLowerCase());

      return playerName;
    }).toList();
    setState(() => players = suggestions.isEmpty ? allPayers : suggestions);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your SearchFilterBar widget. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes it was missing Expanded to wrap the Listview.builder in both I have edited the code

Comment: Add the following properties in your listview.builder:
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), It will fix the rendering issue.

Comment: Actually the problem is how to display a non filtered list clicking on suffix icon